# angular material - animation transition start state is not updated after sorting the material table

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-animations

Animation transition start state is not updated after sorting on a column in the table. I have the code running here - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9uht9-fmjyye)

Steps to reproduce -

1. Immediately after page load, click on "sysbol" header to sort the table
2. Click on the first element
3. Notice that the animation to expand the row to show the details is not working.

Expectation - On clicking of the row, it should expand to show its details.

I added the animation start and done handlers and printed the details onto the console. One thing I noticed is that on sorting, the state of the animation is reset to "void". So on click, the initial state is printed as "void" and not "collapsed". Due to which the animation transition is not happening.

Can anyone provide a fix for this without changing the transition start state to void in the ts file?

Note :

- This issue is only on the immediate click after sorting the table. Subsequent clicks seem to work as expected.
- I have gone through [this](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11990#issue-337153871) and it just appears to be a work around than an actual fix.